# Gutenberg - reusable blocks that I can edit? Am I being slow?

Tags: block-editor

I'm either being incredibly stupid or I've misunderstood a "reusable" Gutenberg block.

If I make a block that I need to reuse then it is all very simple to save it and it's placed with the reusable library.

However, if I insert it back into the page and try and edit it then edits the entire block.

My point is that all I want to do is edit the text - not the layout.

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reusable block is meant to be a global block...meaning that you can insert it on any page and if the content is updated, it will update across the entire site. This is handy, for instance, for call-to-action content.

However, if you want to have a reusable block that has all of the same styling and features, but just need to change the text, you can convert an instance of that block back to a `regular block` by clicking on the three dots (block settings) menu and clicking "Convert to Regular Block":

[image]